# DocuSign Api returning filebytes string, getting blank or corrupted file when try to convert to PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf-generation, docusignapi

I'm working with the docusign api in order to get some documents from envelopes, I get all the info, but for the PDF download I get a "filebytes" string, and when trying to process it to download it, I get just a blank page (not sure if that's the expecting result since I'm using sandbox account). I'm doing all this from the client.

here's what I'm doing to process the string:

```
      const pdfBlob = new Blob([Buffer.from(content)], {
    type: 'application/pdf'
  });

  if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(pdfBlob, filename);
    resolve();
  } else {
    const tempLink = document.createElement('a');
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(pdfBlob);

    const clickEvent = new MouseEvent('click', {
      'view': window,
      'bubbles': true,
      'cancelable': false
    });
    tempLink.href = url;
    tempLink.target = '_blank';
    tempLink.download = filename;
    document.body.appendChild(tempLink);
    tempLink.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.body.removeChild(tempLink);
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      resolve();
    }, 100);
  }


});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [blog post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-common-api-tasks-downloading-documents/) on this topic.
The Node.js code is this (you have to do this from server):

```
// You would need to obtain an accessToken using your chosen auth flow 
let apiClient = new ApiClient(basePath);
let config = new docusign.Configuration(apiClient);
config.addDefaultHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
let envelopesApi = new docusign.EnvelopesApi(config); 
var accountId; // accountId for your DocuSign account
var envelopeId; // envelopeId that you are working on
// produce a ZIP file with all documents including the CoC
let results1 = await envelopesApi.GetDocument(accountId, envelopeId, 'archive', null);
// produce a PDF combining all signed documents as well as the CoC
let results2 = await envelopesApi.GetDocument(accountId, envelopeId, 'combined', null);
// produce a particular document with documentId '1'
let results3 = await envelopesApi.GetDocument(accountId, envelopeId, '1', null);
//TODO - use byte array to write or send the file for your use
```

If your code or this code returns an empty page, please confirm that you don't get it if you use the DocuSign web app, it's possible it is empty?
Please remember encoding, this is using 64 bit encoding to get bits in the REST API.

Comment: I have this same issue, do you happen to know how to write any of those results to a file and not get a corrupt file?

Comment: I'm not sure why you get a corrupt file, which lang do you use? do you get the PDF directly and that works ok?

Comment: I'm using node: https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-node-auth-code-grant/blob/master/lib/examples/eg007EnvelopeGetDoc.js#L141

Using binary encoding when writing the file works just fine.

Comment: Nothing, it works just fine. I can see how my comment was unclear